# Object creating object

Tags: java, bluej

I'm a very new programmer-in-training, and this problem on my assignment has me absolutely stumped. We are currently working on creating objects with objects, and I'm completely lost. I have a MediaDemo class that's supposed to create an instance from the Book class. I felt I was getting close for a bit but the error keeps saying that it can't accept the variable type... Here's the code from both classes:

```
    public class Book 
{ 
    // The fields. 
    private String author; 
    private String title;
    private int pages;
    private String refNumber;
    private int borrowed;
    private boolean courseText;

/** 
 * Set the author and title fields when this object 
* is constructed. 
*/ 
    public Book( String bookAuthor, String bookTitle, int bookPages, boolean theCourseText) 
   { 
       author = bookAuthor; 
        title = bookTitle;
        pages = bookPages;
        refNumber = ("");
        courseText = theCourseText;
    }

public String printAuthor()
{
return author;
}

public String printTitle()
{
return title;
}

public void setRefNumber(String ref)
{
if(ref.length() == 3){
refNumber = ref;
}
else{
System.out.println("Please enter a String that's 3 characters long.");
}
}

public String printRef()
{
return refNumber;
}

public void borrow()
{
    borrowed += 1;
}
public int getBorrowed()
{
    return borrowed;
}

public void printDetails()
{
if(refNumber == ("")) {
System.out.println("Book Author: " + author + ". | Book Title: " + title + ". | Book Length: " + pages + " pages. refNumber: ZZZ | Borrowed Books: " + borrowed);
}
else {
System.out.println("Book Author: " + author + ". | Book Title: " + title + ". | Book Length: " + pages + " pages. | Number: " + refNumber + ". | Borrowed Books:     " + borrowed);
}
}
}
```

Thanks for any help on this, I'll be glad as soon as I find a solution that prevents me from beating my head on my desk...

--UPDATED--

```
/**
 * Write a description of class MediaDemo here.
 * 
 * @author ---
 * @version 2-17-16
 */
public class MediaDemo
{
 private Book book;
 private String bookAuthor;
 private String bookTitle;
 private int bookPages;
 private boolean theCourseText;
 public MediaDemo (String author,String title,int pages,boolean courseBook)
 {
     bookAuthor = author;
     bookTitle = title;
     bookPages = pages;
     theCourseText = courseBook;
     createBook();
 }

 private void createBook()

{
  book = new Book(bookAuthor, bookTitle, bookPages, theCourseText);
}
}
```

Okay, this is the currect version of Book.

Comment: Please give any specific errors in your posts.

Comment: You have used a parameterized constructor in book but while instantiating your not passing parameters.

Comment: The Specific Error is:

Comment: Book book = new Book(author, title, bookPages,theCourseText) ;

Comment: constructor Book in class Book cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.String, java.int,boolean  found: no arguments              Sorry about that! This is my first time posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `book = new Book();` instantiates a new object book and when you say new Book(), it means calling to the Book constructor

```
public Book( String bookAuthor, String bookTitle, int bookPages, boolean theCourseText) 
   { 
       author = bookAuthor; 
        title = bookTitle;
        pages = bookPages;
        refNumber = "(\"\")"; \\result : ("")
        courseText = theCourseText;
    }
```

. In your code, you didn't supply the arguments needed to create a new instance of the object book. So you might try replacing :

```
book = new Book();
```

with

```
book = new Book( "Scarlet", "I dunnu", 100, true);
```

of course with the corresponding data types for the parameters

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, everyone! I have replaced the errored code with your suggestion, and I know get this error after the first 'String'

Comment: ')' expected     --- I am using BlueJ, not sure if I mentioned this.

Comment: oh yeah. I didn't see that. :)

Comment: Thank you very much Jan for your help, here is the new code:

Comment: I editted the original post to cover the new code ^-^ This website is really neat!

Comment: What happened to the arguments??? did (bookAuthor, bookTitle, bookPages, theCourseText) already have their values? because I think they don't have yet.

Comment: I updated my answer. kindly take a look especially the refNumber. @Scarlet

Comment: No they don't. I think I'm just confused by my professor's instructions. These are the instructions: Add another new class, MediaDemo to your Book exercise.
Add a field to your class for a Book object. -Good from here up-
Write a private method that will build a book object with all the fields populated, and return that book object.
Write a constructor for your MediaDemo class that will initialize the Book field by calling the private method you just wrote. -cont-

Comment: -cont- Add a new method, testBook, that will print out the initial state of your Book field, then change values for the book’s fields – print out what you are changing, and print the final state of your book object.

Comment: Ah, I just saw your edit, that makes a lot more sense x.x Thanks, will input the code and see what happens. Sorry for being such a newbie, I don't know why this concept is taking me by surprise when I've dabbled in several other languages before.

Comment: Okay, I have added the new parameters and input them during runtime. It takes all the data, but it doesn't create the new instance on the bench. There aren't anymore syntax errors so I'm assuming I've done something wrong again...

Comment: Try checking for logical errors... Thats the hardest part in programming I say.

Comment: I will, thank you so much for all your help! I have to head off, but is there anyway to mail/email people on here? Thanks again!

Comment: but you can put a check on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a parameterized constructor in book... 
But when you are calling you are calling a non parameterized constructor..

So the code should be

```
Book book = new Book(author, title, bookPages, theCourseText) ;
```

Yes it will create a new instance and while creating will call the parameterized constructor.. 
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

In MediaDemo Class you are calling a default constructor Book() 
but its not declared in Book Class. Since you have a explicit constructor
public Book( String bookAuthor, String bookTitle, int bookPages, boolean theCourseText)
you need to use it or declare a dafault constructor explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Before calling below line you must have all the arguments assigned with some values
book = new Book( bookAuthor, bookTitle, bookPages, theCourseText);